# Download locally Windows Azure website

Tags: wordpress, azure

I created a new Wordpress/MySql website on Windows Azure. Can I download the entire website with database to host locally on my machine?

I can use FTP to download website files, but what about DB and other configuration if there is any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Connect through FTP do copy Wordpress file. Open wp-config.php and take the connection string. After that, you can connect through Mysql using Worchbench and export database.